# How to use multicolumn under multicolumn

Tags: tables, multicolumn

In the following table, I want to use 2 columns under D & 3 columns under F.
How to do this?

```
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|cc|c|}
     \hline
      
    A    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{B}  & C\\
     \hline
                              &  D & F & \\
      \hline
      
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Is this the expected output?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/peOjl.png

Comment: Yes, I want that.

Comment: Should the 7 cells in the bottom row all have the exact same width?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
      \hline
      A    & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{B}                           & C\\
      \hline
           &  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{D} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{F} & \\
      \hline
           & 1 & 2                   & 1 & 2 & 3              & \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines]{ccccccc}
A & \Block{1-5}{B} &&&&& C \\
  & \Block{1-2}{D} && \Block{1-3}{F} \\
  & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 3):

For sake of completeness let me add solution by use of the new LaTeX-3 package `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines, cells={c}}
A   & \SetCell[c=5]{c}  B
        &   &   &   &   & C \\
    & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  D
        &   & \SetCell[c=3]{c}  F
                &   &   &   \\
    & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 &   \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]